# DocumentDB Stored Procedure Lumenize

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, lumenize

I'm using the aggregate stored procedure lumenize https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize with the .net client and I'm in trouble in the filterquery content.

How simply pass alphanumeric value to the filterquery query ?

```
string configString = @"{
cubeConfig: {
     groupBy: 'Modele', 
     field: 'Distance', 
     f: 'sum'
     }, 
     filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM Modele WHERE ModeleGUID = ''0b93def1-ccd7-fc35-0475-b47c89137c3f'' '}";
```

Each test gives me a parse error in the filterquery :(

> Error: One or more errors occurred.
>   Message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered:
>   '. Path 'filterQuery', line 7, position 63.
>   End of demo, press any key to exit.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect it's related to the multiple single-quotes you have in your filter string. That doesn't look right. Have you tried escape-quoting (`\'`) ?

Comment: Yes !! stupid I am... thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted as an answer so this can be resolved properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to properly close this out: The issue is related to multiple single-quotes in the filter string. As long as they're escaped properly (e.g. `\'`), things should work as expected.